# how to filter models on django-admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models:

```html
class Contrato(models.Model):
    active= models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Activo?")
    .....

    def __str__(self,):
        return str(self.id) + '- ' + str(self.forcenedor)

class Fatura(models.Model):
    contrato = models.ForeignKey(Contrato, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Contrato")
    designação =  models. CharField(verbose_name="Designação",max_length=30)
    ..............

    def __str__(self,):
        return str(self.id)
```

When I'm adding a new "*Fatura*" in my django-admin , i want to only show the "*Contrato*" that is true on "**active**"

This type of filter , do i need to do in my admin file or i can do here directly on my models files? and how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(FaturaAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj=obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['contrato'].queryset = Contrato.objects.filter(active=True)
    return form
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your admin.py file

```
from .models import Contrato
from django.contrib import admin
class ContratoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

        def get_queryset(self, request):
        """Make a queryset for list of results.
        """
            qs = super().get_queryset(request)

            return qs.filter(active=True)

admin.site.register(Contrato, ContratoAdmin)
```

According to your comment you do the following.
You need to overwrite get_form method in admin.py file.

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form.base_fields['contrato'].queryset = Contrato.objects.filter(active=True)
```

Comment: In fact it works, but it does not do what I intend to do, maybe because I explained myself wrong. I want all the list if is not active or active, i just want to filter when i am adding a new *fatura*

Comment: In that case you need to overwrite get_form method in admin.py file.
 
 def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
  form.base_fields['contrato'].queryset = Contrato.objects.filter(active=True)

Comment: `form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)`
`form.base_fields['contrato'].queryset = Contrato.objects.filter(active=True)`
`return form`

Answer (score 0):

To filter all active contracts you must use Contrato's object manager

```
active_contracts = Contrato.objects.filter(active=True)
```